# Can't get index in array of CLLocation Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexof

I'm writing my own locations filter function because I seriously find the `LocationManager()` options to be quite useless.. very imprecise and any settings I tried following dozens of guide in post always led to very poor tracking... I mean horrible.. 
I was actually implement this filtering directly in `didUpdateLocations`but as soon you get to far then any following location gets discarded. Personal opinions apart, I basically accept every incoming location apart the ones with `horizontal accuracy < 0` and then when I stop getting new locations I filter the array out following parameters like `minDistance`and `maxDistance`from previous saved location, `timestamp`, and `speed`. But as I tried it steady at  home I noticed that dough it's looping fine, it doesn't filter out anything as the prints show because I'm getting the index wrong. Can you see how should I get the index? As always many thanks for your help.

This is the function:

```
func filterInvalidLocation(route: [CLLocation]) -> [CLLocation] {
        var routeFiltered = route
        for location in routeFiltered {
            print("processing location is \(location)")
            let index = routeFiltered[0].index(ofAccessibilityElement: location)
            print("index is : \(index)")
            if index > 0 && index <= routeFiltered.capacity{

                // invalid
                if location.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("location removed : invalid")
                }
                // too low accuracy
                if location.horizontalAccuracy > 80 {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("location removed : low accuracy")
                }
                // not sequential
                if location.timestamp < routeFiltered[index - 1].timestamp {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("location removed : not sequential")
                }
                // too far
                if location.distance(from: routeFiltered[index - 1]) > maxDistance {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("locatione removed : too far")
                }
                // too close
                if location.distance(from: routeFiltered[index - 1]) < minDistance {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("location removed : too close")
                }
                // not mooving
                if location.speed < 1 {
                    routeFiltered.remove(at: index)
                    print("location removed : not mooving")
                }
            }
        }
        print("routeFiltered is \(routeFiltered)")
        return routeFiltered
    }
```

And this it the console print:

> processing location is <+44.50137329,+11.33594359> +/- 65.00m (speed
>   -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:09 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale index is : 9223372036854775807 processing
>   location is <+44.50140045,+11.33594359> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps /
>   course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:07 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale
>   index is : 9223372036854775807 processing location is
>   <+44.50140053,+11.33594337> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course
>   -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:22 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale index is : 9223372036854775807 processing location is
>   <+44.50140056,+11.33594332> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course
>   -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:37 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale index is : 9223372036854775807 routeFiltered is [<+44.50137329,+11.33594359>
>   +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:09 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale, <+44.50140045,+11.33594359> +/- 65.00m
>   (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:07 Ora standard
>   dell’Europa centrale, <+44.50140053,+11.33594337> +/- 65.00m (speed
>   -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:22 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale, <+44.50140056,+11.33594332> +/- 65.00m (speed
>   -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 03/12/19, 13:16:37 Ora standard dell’Europa centrale] MapArray.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.count
>   is: 4

Comment: What is `index` supposed to contain, what is the expected result of calling `index(ofAccessibilityElement: location)`? If it is expected to be a position in the array then what has `index(ofAccessibilityElement: location)` got to do with anything?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes you're absolutely right , it's wrong. I indeed need the position in the array.

Comment: `index(ofAccessibilityElement:)` vs `firstIndex(where:)`?

Comment: @Larme I tried `if  let index = routeFiltered.firstIndex(where: { $0 == location })` and `if  let index = routeFiltered.index(where: { $0 === location })` but index prints `function` not an `Int`.. so when I try to read previous value it crashes with `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` .

Comment: I don't understand why you search the index on `routeFiltered[0]`, but then apply/test on `routeFiltered` directly.

Comment: I know, it was just wrong.. I did change it. Still `index` doesn't seem to be an `Int` as I get `index is : (Function)`from printing it.

Comment: Not tested, but https://pastebin.com/RnfTA8nw Possible issues: I might have inversed some guard test (like > instead of <, etc.), and it's checking against last valid previous in array, not against previous location in array, might have impact. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Side note: I forgot the sequential test too*

Comment: @ Larme Thanks I had this idea too but I thought It would be easier to remove a location from the array in a `for` loop. I might just go the other way though  way. By the way indexed is now corrected, a minor tweak and I should het this code working, but I'll try the other way and tell how it turned out. Thanks

Comment: @Larme I'm trying your code and it throws me a `[NSMutableOrderedSet addObject:]: object cannot be nil'`error every time.. can you see why?

Comment: My code shouldn’t. Is it afterwards?

Comment: `guard let last = accumulated.last else { return }`, should be `guard let last = accumulated.last else { accumulated.append(currentLocation); return }` inside the else, else, there is no "initial value", it's always empty.

Comment: @Larme yes indeed.. I did see it after a bit of thinking, as my version of using another array to store valid locations did just that, otherwise there is no first location.. I like the reduced version as is cleaner, my version is a series of nested `if`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `reduce(into:)`. It's easier to play with "previous index".

```
func filterInvalidLocation(route: [CLLocation]) -> [CLLocation] {

    let maxDistance = 500000.0
    let minDistance = 10000.0
    let reduced = route.reduce(into: [CLLocation]()) { (accumulated, currentLocation) in
        // We don't add it if negative horizontal accuracy 
        guard currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because of horizontalAccuracy being negative")
            return
        }
         // We don't add it if Low Accuracy
        guard currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 80 else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because of horizontalAccuracy being > 80")
            return
        }
        // We don't add it if not moving
        guard currentLocation.speed > 1 else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because of speed < 1")
            return
        }

        guard let last = accumulated.last else {
            //There is no valid one yet to compare, we consider this one as valid
            accumulated.append(currentLocation)
            return
        }

        //We check if there location is "newer"
        guard last.timestamp < currentLocation.timestamp else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because distance is older than previous one")
            return
        }

        let distanceFromLast = currentLocation.distance(from: last)
        print(distanceFromLast)
        // We don't add it distance between last and current is too big
        guard distanceFromLast < maxDistance else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because distance is too big (\(distanceFromLast))")
            return
        }
        // We don't add it distance between last and current is too low
        guard distanceFromLast > minDistance else {
            print("\(currentLocation) removed because distance is too small (\(distanceFromLast))")
            return
        }
        //Current Location passed all test, we add it
        accumulated.append(currentLocation)
    }
    return reduced
}
```

With sample:

```
let date = Date()

let locations: [CLLocation] = [CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: -1.0,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 90,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 0.1,
                                          timestamp: date),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date.addingTimeInterval(-1.0)),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.0, longitude: 50.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date.addingTimeInterval(+1.0)),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.001, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date.addingTimeInterval(+2.0)),
                               CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 31.0, longitude: 45.0),
                                          altitude: 30.0,
                                          horizontalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          verticalAccuracy: 0.1,
                                          course: 0.1,
                                          speed: 2,
                                          timestamp: date.addingTimeInterval(+1.0)),
                                ]
```

This can be tested on playground, we should keep the first one and the one at index 7.

Comment: It all works as expected and filters out unwanted locations, but I have to omit the speed cause it always reads -1, from actual iPhone not simulator. but with the right minimum distance, I could get rid of those false locations too